# problema para resetar CountDownTimer

Tags: java, android

Estou montando um projeto para ir aprendendo e não consigo achar uma solução para um timer, digamos que tempo já foi selecionado 10 minutos e o usuario quer mudar para 5 minutos ao clicar em 5 min deveria cancelar o tempo antigo e iniciar o novo mas não consigo implementa isso, segue o código :

```
if (TIMER != null) {
  TIMER.cancel();
  display.setText("00:00");
} else if (TIMER == null) {
  TIMER = new CountDownTimer(300000, 1000) {
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
      display.setText("Tempo restante: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
    }
    public void onFinish() {
      display.setText("00:00");
      pausarMusica();
    }
  }.start();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acho que você está esquecendo de setar o TIMER para `null` quando você chama o `TIMER.cancel();`. Já que você está usando o fato do `TIMER` ser `null` ou não como flag.

Depois da primeira execução, de acordo com o seu código, ele nunca mais vai ser null, logo, nunca vai cair no segundo if.

Isso deve funcionar:

```
if (TIMER != null) {
      TIMER.cancel();
      TIMER = null;
      display.setText("00:00");
    } else if (TIMER == null) {
      TIMER = new CountDownTimer(300000, 1000) {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
          display.setText("Tempo restante: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
        }
        public void onFinish() {
          display.setText("00:00");
          pausarMusica();
        }
      }.start();
    }
```

Comment: então, pensei bem como não estava nem assim caindo no segundo if e o código executa de cima pra baixo simplesmente retirei o else if e deixei o restante do código fora, funcionou! obrigado!